# vertical lines inside circles - with hover effects

Tags: css

I want to draw lines inside circles pointing to the "concepts of the process" as it is shown in the the below image[![enter image description here][1]][1],moreover , the lines will take the same hover effects applied on the circles . please advise .

you can find the link from which i intend to imitate the same process :
https://rudo.studio/

```css
.dot {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: whitesmoke;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 9%;
  margin: 9% -15px 0;
  padding: 8%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  bottom: 10px;
}
.dot:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  border-color: black;
}

.dot::after {
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;

  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: inherit;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 4px;
  position: relative;
}

.dot::before {
  content: "";
  border-left: 2px solid whitesmoke;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: -4px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  bottom: 7px;
}
.processItems {
  color: #fff;
  font: 19px SuisseIntl-SemiBold, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  word-spacing: 99px;
  display: inherit;
  text-align: justify;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div ID="process" class="process">
      <h1> Our Process</h1>
      <p ID="ourProcess2">Every project is unique but we have established a framework on how we approach things to maximise the success rate. Our Design & Development process has been tested on multiple projects. It is Agile, End User-Focused and transparent for our Clients.</p>
      
      <div class="processItems">
        <p1 class="Discovery">Discovery</p1>
        <p2 class="Prototypes">Prototypes</p2>
        <p3 class="desgn">Design</p3>
        <p4 class="Development">Development</p4>
        <p5 class="maintenance">Maintenance</p5>
      </div>
      
      
     
      
      <div class="circleProcess">
       
        <span ID="cricle1" class="dot"data-description="Work starts before the work starts. Market research and analysis, competitor research, design and branding preferences. We don't begin any design work until there is a clear understanding of the Business Case and User Personas."></span>
        <span ID="cricle2"class="dot" data-description="We start with a user flow map to gain a bird's eye view of the entire project. This is followed by Wireframes and clickable Prototypes which establish the overall structure, content and functionality of the project."></span>
        <span ID="cricle3"class="dot" data-description="User Interface design is the stage when the overall look &amp; feel of the project is established. We work with colors, typography, visual effects and animations. This is what the end users will see when they interact with your product/website."></span>
        <span ID="cricle4"class="dot" data-description="This is when it all comes to life in terms of functionality. Producing an efficient clean code structure is our goal at this stage. We usually work with popular platforms such as WordPress or HubSpot to make it easy for our clients to manage and edit the website in the future."></span>
        <span ID="cricle5"class="dot" data-description="We make sure that everything runs, every day, exactly as it should. Our maintenance packages include regular security audits, weekly code back-ups, and server load monitoring. We are flexible and can tailor our support services based on the specific needs our clients have."></span>
      </div>

   
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't know why i can't change the "height" of the lines ?

Comment: set the `position` of the lines to `absolute`

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` for line and dot to get center to circle also change in height, top and left of line css

```css
.dot {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: whitesmoke;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 9%;
  margin: 9% -15px 0;
  padding: 8%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  bottom: 10px;
}
.dot:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  border-color: black;
}
.dot:hover:before{
  border-left-color:black;
}
.dot:hover:after{
  background-color:black;
}

.dot::after {
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.dot::before {
  content: "";
  border-left: 2px solid whitesmoke;
  height: calc(50% + 25px);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: -25px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.processItems {
  color: #fff;
  font: 19px SuisseIntl-SemiBold, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  word-spacing: 99px;
  display: inherit;
  text-align: justify;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div ID="process" class="process">
      <h1> Our Process</h1>
      <p ID="ourProcess2">Every project is unique but we have established a framework on how we approach things to maximise the success rate. Our Design & Development process has been tested on multiple projects. It is Agile, End User-Focused and transparent for our Clients.</p>
      
      <div class="processItems">
        <p1 class="Discovery">Discovery</p1>
        <p2 class="Prototypes">Prototypes</p2>
        <p3 class="desgn">Design</p3>
        <p4 class="Development">Development</p4>
        <p5 class="maintenance">Maintenance</p5>
      </div>      
      
      <div class="circleProcess">
       
        <span ID="cricle1" class="dot"data-description="Work starts before the work starts. Market research and analysis, competitor research, design and branding preferences. We don't begin any design work until there is a clear understanding of the Business Case and User Personas."></span>
        <span ID="cricle2"class="dot" data-description="We start with a user flow map to gain a bird's eye view of the entire project. This is followed by Wireframes and clickable Prototypes which establish the overall structure, content and functionality of the project."></span>
        <span ID="cricle3"class="dot" data-description="User Interface design is the stage when the overall look &amp; feel of the project is established. We work with colors, typography, visual effects and animations. This is what the end users will see when they interact with your product/website."></span>
        <span ID="cricle4"class="dot" data-description="This is when it all comes to life in terms of functionality. Producing an efficient clean code structure is our goal at this stage. We usually work with popular platforms such as WordPress or HubSpot to make it easy for our clients to manage and edit the website in the future."></span>
        <span ID="cricle5"class="dot" data-description="We make sure that everything runs, every day, exactly as it should. Our maintenance packages include regular security audits, weekly code back-ups, and server load monitoring. We are flexible and can tailor our support services based on the specific needs our clients have."></span>
      </div>

   
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Minal Chauhan